# Expressing stopping work early

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, synonyms

Is it correct to say - I will stop work early before 8 pm from now onwards? 
 is there a better way or more elegant way to express this?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Rohit!  We need more information about your question.  Who are you saying this to?  How *early* are you stopping work from now on?  Five minutes, ten minutes, four hours?  A little background information will help us understand what precisely you are wanting to say.

Answer (score 1):

"From now onward," implies a permanent change of work schedule. Colloquially, one might say, "My schedule needs to be changed so that I leave by 8 PM, starting tomorrow." This is not as concise as your original sentence, but offers more explanation and put it a bit more politely, rather than stating, "I will stop..."